# Mongoose populating an object in an array, only one value is good

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I try unsuccessfully to accept an array using populate...

my Objects:

```
var giftSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  prod_id :Number,
  price : Number,
  interests : [{ type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'inGiftInterSchema'}],
  gender : String,
  store_id : String,
  store_name: String,
  age: Number
});

var inGiftInterSchema = new Schema({
  interest: String,
  dynamicScore: Number
});
```

this is where I'm trying to get for each gift in my DB all its interests:

```
function giftSearch(maxPrice ,minPrice,age, interests ,res) {

  Gift.find({}).populate('interests').exec(function(err,gifter) {

    res.render('resultPage');

  });
}
```

I get an array name "gifter" that only in the second place (gifter[1]._doc.interests) i have the models (inGiftInterSchema) that I wanted, in all of the other 6 gifts that I have in gifter (and in my DB) the intetersts array size is 0...

THANKS!  :)